# MQ Upgrading 7.5 to 8

Tags: ibm-mq

I have upgraded to IBM MQ 7.5 to 8.0.

Beforehand I was using SSL. Since SSL is disabled in MQ8. I have to use TLS. But the question is do I need to create the certificate again to use with MQ 8 after upgrading process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the certificate is independent of the protocol used.